# Regex to check beginning of international phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, phone-number

I am trying to create a regex that validates the 2 first characters of an international phone number as the user types it in:

Is valid: `+`, `0`, `+ followed by a number`, `00`, `0032476382763`, `+324763`

Is not valid: `0 followed by a number different than 0`, `++`, `everything that is not in the valid list`

So far I have come up with:

```
/[0]|[00]|[+]|[+\d]]/g
```

But this validates `++` but not `+2`. The problem is that I can't figure out how to validate depending on the number of characters (1 or 2).

I am using that expression in `javascript`. Here's the regex I worked on: http://regexr.com/3br5v

My level in regex is not very good, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Which language is this for? Perl/C#/...?

Comment: @rbm I edited my post

Comment: Note that in your examples, you're using `[]` incorrectly. `[]` denotes a *character class*, so `[0]` will only match zeros and `[00]` is exactly the same as `[0]`. It's not a grouping construct.

Comment: So `00` is a valid telephone number? As far as I know that's only a prefix.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Sorry, brain skipped a beat. The `+` stands in for "whatever you need for an international line," which is what I was thinking of.

Comment: I said as the user types it in, so 00 is not incorrect

Comment: I added a link to regexr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick (fixed bug with false positive `01`):

```
/^([+]|00|0$)(\d*)$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/qT0dB7/2

Comment: Oops, it seems `01` is a false positive, trying to fix.

Comment: Updated regex in post

Answer (score 1):

```js
\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$
```

You can use if you want to validate full an international number.

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern works for a large sample:

```
((?:\+(?!\+)|0(?:(?![1-9])))\d*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bL0uX9/2

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^[1-9]\d|\+[1-9]|00
```